# SonarQube Installation - Github Authentication plugin fails with "PKIX path building failed"

Tags: ssl, sonarqube, ssl-certificate, certificate-authority, sonarqube-ops

I'm trying to get the plugin to work. Sonarsource 5.6, plugin 1.2. I'm having an SSL error which I think is caused by my instance of github enterprise having an SSL cert granted from an internal-and-therefore-untrusted CA (or perhaps simply not set up right). The log is copied in below.

What options do I have? I think

- I can download the certs via `sudo docker exec <my container id> openssl s_client -connect my-sonarqube-hostname:443 -showcerts` and then (if I knew what I was doing) use `keytool` to ... poke it into the store (?)
- I could disable cert validation a) if I knew how, and b) if I thought it was ok to risk MITM for something that's going to have my source code in it (I don't)
- I could try to understand articles like below but they all seem to involve compiling something to fetch the cert to put it into the store

  - https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/unable-to-connect-to-ssl-services-due-to-pkix-path-building-failed-779355358.html
- I could try to get the team that owns GHE to use a real cert
- ....? anything else?

I'm running sonarqube within a docker container on an Amazon Linux EC2 instance - very easy to get going with, but now tricky to modify (though I suppose I could pull the Dockerfile and fork it - I doubt my problem is unique for internal setups, so maybe whatever I come up with is worth contributing back?)

Logs:

```
    2016.06.10 07:50:01 ERROR web[o.s.s.a.AuthenticationError] Fail to callback authentication with 'github'
com.github.scribejava.core.exceptions.OAuthConnectionException: There was a problem while creating a connection to the remote service: https://my-github-enterprise-hostname/login/oauth/access_token?client_id=02e2f2cd8f567478c80d&client_secret=68c1ec2fe7d5c99a75e478c476965bdbefdc55dd&code=1b8c6e1323ef66e7a8f0&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmy-sonarqube-hostname%2Foauth2%2Fcallback%2Fgithub
        at com.github.scribejava.core.model.OAuthRequest.send(OAuthRequest.java:39) ~[na:na]
        at com.github.scribejava.core.oauth.OAuth20ServiceImpl.getAccessToken(OAuth20ServiceImpl.java:36) ~[na:na]
        at org.sonarsource.auth.github.GitHubIdentityProvider.callback(GitHubIdentityProvider.java:111) ~[na:na]
        at org.sonar.server.authentication.OAuth2CallbackFilter.doFilter(OAuth2CallbackFilter.java:71) ~[sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.MasterServletFilter$GodFilterChain.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:125) [sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.MasterServletFilter.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:94) [sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.sonar.server.user.UserSessionFilter.doFilter(UserSessionFilter.java:59) [sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.sonar.server.platform.ProfilingFilter.doFilter(ProfilingFilter.java:84) [sonar-server-5.6.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at ch.qos.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackValve.invoke(LogbackValve.java:191) [logback-access-1.1.3.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_91]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at com.github.scribejava.core.model.Response.<init>(Response.java:30) ~[na:na]
        at com.github.scribejava.core.model.OAuthRequest.doSend(OAuthRequest.java:57) ~[na:na]
        at com.github.scribejava.core.model.OAuthRequest.send(OAuthRequest.java:37) ~[na:na]
        ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        ... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        ... 47 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up doing

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST=my-github-hostname
PORT=443
KEYSTOREFILE=/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts
KEYSTOREPASS=changeit

# get the SSL certificate
openssl s_client -connect ${HOST}:${PORT} </dev/null | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > ${HOST}.cert

# copy it into the running docker container
sudo docker cp ${HOST}.cert sonarqube-web:/opt/sonarqube/${HOST}.cert

# import certificate into the container's keystore

sudo docker exec sonarqube-web keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias ${HOST} -file /opt/sonarqube/${HOST}.cert -keystore ${KEYSTOREFILE} -storepass ${KEYSTOREPASS}

# verify we've got it.
sudo docker exec sonarqube-web keytool -list -v -keystore ${KEYSTOREFILE} -storepass ${KEYSTOREPASS} -alias ${HOST}

exit 0
```

I realise modifying the running docker container is probably something I'll burn for, but OTOH the instance will fetch a fresh copy of the cert each time it bootstraps, so...

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your Enterprise Github URL is not signed with a certificate your application server accepts.

You have to add your servers SSL key to your application servers keystore ([see corresponding documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Prepare_the_Certificate_Keystore) for details using the keytool from JDK).

Comment: That diagnosis was exactly right. Thanks; I'd got that far. I found the documentation that you pointed at not so helpful to someone as unfamiliar with java as me, so I wrote some script with the actual commands spelled out.